# How to pass numbers into a vector as a function parameter C++

Tags: c++, function, vector, parameters, numbers

The function FLIP takes the 4 parameters. n,number of elements of a vector ,v the vector ,i and j ,random numbers. The function will look like this FLIP(n,v,i,j). What it does is that it takes all of the elements of the vector from i to j and reverses them. For example FLIP(9, [3 2 6 8 5 9 1 7 4], 1, 6) should return v = [9 5 8 6 2 3 1 7 4].

TL/DR : I don't know how to pass the numbers [3 2 6 8 5 9 1 7 4] as parameters and give the vector these values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void FLIP(int n,vector<int>& v,int i,int j)
{
    int k,l,aux;

    for(k=i;k<=j;k++)
    {
        for(l=j;l>=i;j--)
        {
            aux=v[k];
            v[k]=v[l];
            v[l]=aux;
        }
    }

}
int main()
{

int i,v[50];
FLIP(9,[3 2 6 8 5 9 1 7 4],1,6);
for(i=1;i<=9;i++)
{
    cout<<v[i]<<" ";
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Research `std::swap`, `std::reverse`, `std::rotate`, `uniform initialization`, `std::vector`, `std::tuple`, references, and more.

Comment: You are not using the parameter 'n', why not get rid of it as long as the other 2 parameters are less than the size of the vector?

Comment: @Gardener My assignment specifies that the function should look like this FLIP(n,v,i,j). You are right though, it doesn't use the n parameter but I don't really know how they want me to use it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

syntax would be

```
{3, 2, 6, 8, 5, 9, 1, 7, 4}
```

and not

```
[3 2 6 8 5 9 1 7 4]
```

But in addition, you cannot bind temporary to non const reference.

You might change your `main` to:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {3, 2, 6, 8, 5, 9, 1, 7, 4};
    FLIP(9, v, 1, 6);
    for (auto e : v)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I did as instructed and get the error |28|error: in C++98 'v' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'|   and   |28|error: could not convert '{3, 2, 6, 8, 5, 9, 1, 7, 4}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<int>'|

Comment: @BugaAndrei: Use more recent standard as C++11/C++14/C++17 (`-std=c++17` for gcc/clang for example).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is somewhat confusing due to the conflicting definitions of your vector.  In `main()`, v is defined as a char array: `v[50]`.  However, in FLIP, it is defined as a vector.

Since the better way to do this is with std::vector, all comments have leaned in that direction.  Here is one possible implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print_vector(vector<int> v) {
  for(const auto& element: v) {
    cout<<element<<" ";
  }
  cout << "\n";
}

void FLIP(int n, vector<int>& v,int i,int j)
{
  // i is 1-based index into vector to starting position
  // j is 1-based index to ending position
  // check to be sure i and j are valid for this vector:
  if(i < 1 || i > j || j > v.size()) {
    cout << "invalid arguments\n";
    return;
  }
  reverse(v.begin() + i - 1, v.begin() + j);
}
 


int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vect{3, 2, 6, 8, 5, 9, 1, 7, 4};
  std::cout << "Print vector before ...\n\t";
  print_vector(vect);
  std::cout << "Print vector after ...\n\t";

  FLIP(vect.size(), vect,1,6);

  print_vector(vect);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Print vector before ...
    3 2 6 8 5 9 1 7 4 
Print vector after ...
    3 9 5 8 6 2 1 7 4 

Process finished with exit code 0
```